# fadeIn and fadeOut don't work on elements with a CSS fallback

Tags: jquery, css

I have a normal menu with a dropdown option, developed in the following way:

```
ul > li.dropdown > ul.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  min-width: 100px;
}

ul > li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

When I try to add an animation with `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functions to the dropdown-content, strangely jQuery doesn't add the opacity for the achievement of the animation to the dropdown-content element. If I remove `display:block` from CSS and make handle the hide/block of the element by jQuery, it works suddenly.

There's a way to animate an element that work both in CSS and jQuery? In order to have a fallback if jQuery doesn't load or the user have javascript disabled.

Working animation: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2v047ek/)
Not working animation (with CSS Fallback): [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahoLz8u1/)

Comment: Transitions of opacity are negatively effected by the `display:property` which cannot be transitioned so remove that property.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property

Comment: Why use JavaScript at all? http://jsfiddle.net/4yvakt5o/

Answer (score -2):

You can use visibility: hidden and visibility: visible; for the css fallback.